# How do you make a select dropdown with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, click, focus, html-select

So, I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="toolsIndexSelectContainer">
      <select id="Clients" class="toolsIndexSelect disableElement">
          <option>Item</option>         
          <option>Item 2</option> 
          <option>Item 3</option> 
      </select>
</div>
```

When I click on the surrounding div with class toolsIndexSelectContainer, I would like the select to dropdown and show the items inside.  I have this jQuery:

```
$("div[class~='toolsIndexSelectContainer']").click(function () {
    $(this).children("select").focus();
});
```

But, focus() does not work.  I tried click() and Chrome just blows up on me.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, You cannot do that on `select` element.. You cannot trigger to show the drop down options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use JS to open an HTML select to show it's option list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531882/custom-jquery-dropdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, You cannot do that on `select` element.. You cannot trigger to show the drop down options.

Other option is to download a drop down plugin which basically simulates `select` features.

This [ddSlick](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) plugin seems to simulate select box property and also has a method to open the drop down options.

> **select** You may use plugin's open method like `$('#demoSetSelected').ddslick('open');` to open drop down options.

Comment: This is a bummer.  I wanted add some rounded edges to the select.  I've done it with textboxes.  Oh well, it still looks good.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like the jquery [Combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)
. to convert the select to a combobox. Otherwise this is not possible with a normal select element

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, but seems to work:

```
$(".toolsIndexSelectContainer").click(function () {
    $(this).find("#Clients").focus();
});
$("#Clients").focus(function(){
    this.size=$(this).find('option').length;
}).blur(function(){
    this.size=1;
});
```

fiddle to practice on: http://jsfiddle.net/As93t/